# Custom cells issue in iOS 5

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls

I've a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and I've read that this is supposed to be the correct way of loading custom cells for iOS 5:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];

   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];

      // Configure cell
      cell.nameLabel.text = self.customClass.name;
   }

   return cell;
}
```

But the label text is not shown when I run the app. However, I also tried this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];

   if (cell == nil) {
      NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

   for (UIView *view in views) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCell *)view;
        }
    }

    // Configure cell
    ((CustomCell *)cell).nameLabel.text = self.customClass.name;
}

return cell;
```

}

This way the label is displayed, but any `reuseIdentifier` is set in `loadNibName:` method. What the best way of loading custom cells should be? I need to support iOS 5+. Could the first approach not be working because I'd to configure cell's labels and styles in `initWithStyle:` method and not in the table view's method?

Thanks!

Comment: check whether you are getting data or not in this self.customClass.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your code is that `cell.nameLabel.text` is only set in the `if (cell == nil) { ... }` case and not generally.

The easiest ways to load custom cells are

- Use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` if the cell is defined in a nib file, or
- use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` if the cell is created programmatically, or
- use a Storyboard and define "CustomCell" as "Prototype Cell" for the table view.

For example (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
```

Then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` 
will always return a cell, so that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` simplifies to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
   cell.nameLabel.text = self.customClass.name;
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: A question related to calling those methods... if you want to set, for example, a custom font or another style-related thing for your custom cell in the `UITableViewCell` subclass instead of setting it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, how can you do that?

Comment: @AppsDev: If the cell is loaded from a nib file, you can override `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib`. To modify UI elements in the cell, `awakeFromNib` would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code and try.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSString *customeCellName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[YourCustomCell class]];

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customeCellName owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell =  (YourCustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = self.customClass.name; // Make sure self.customclass.name have value.
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (NewCustomCell is your Custom UITableViewCell class name)...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NewCustomCell *cell = (NewCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"NewCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Happy coding... :)